# Apache Ignite Group By Linq Query Issue

Tags: c#, linq, ignite

i'm trying to join three caches with two of them are left outer joined,also has group by clause. With the below query i ran into strange issue, the generated sql was not correct.

```cs
var query = (from service in serviceCache
            join meetingService in meetingServiceCache.DefaultIfEmpty() on service.Value.ServiceId equals meetingService.Value.ServiceId
            join meeting in meetingCache.DefaultIfEmpty() on meetingService.Value.MeetingId equals meeting.Value.MeetingId
            group new { service, meeting } by service.Value.ServiceId into g
            select new {
               service.Value.ServiceId,
               lastMeeting = g.Select(x=>x.meeting.Value.CreatedDate).Max()
            }).ToCacheQueryable().GetFieldsQuery.Sql;
```

The generated query looks like below

```
select _T0.SERVICEID,min(_T0.CreatedDate) from MEETINGSCHEMA.SERVICES as _T0
left outer join (select _T1.*,_T1.KEY,_T1.VAL from MEETINGSCHEMA.MEETINGSERVICE as _T1) as _T2 on (_T2.SERVICEID= _T0.SERVICEID)
left outer join (select _T3.*,_T3.KEY,_T3.VAL from MEETINGSCHEMA.MEETINGS as _T3) as _T4 on (_T4.MEETINGID= _T3.MEETINGID)
group by (_T0.SERVICEID)
```

In selected columns the createdDate should be selected from _T4 reference,But it's always selected from first table alias thus the query was failing always reporting CreatedDate as invalid column.I Suspect something wrong with linq to sql translation.

Please let me know if i'm doing any mistake. Also the code snippet was typed by hand with out intellisense, pardon me incase of typos.

Comment: I wonder why you have `min` in SQL while `Max` in query

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Can you please provide more details? Ideally, a minimal reproducer.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn, try running below code by placing in CacheLinqTest.Functions.cs file, and check the generated query                                                                                   this persons.Join(orgs.Where(o => o.Key > 10), p => p.Value.OrganizationId, o => o.Key,
                    (p, o) => new { p, o })
                .GroupBy(x => x.o.Value.Name)
                .Select(g => new { Org = g.Key, AgeSum = g.Max(x => x.p.Value.Age) });

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn. Place the below code in Apache.Ignite.Core.Tests.Cache.Query.Linq>CacheLinqTest>TestGroupBy `var query = persons.Join(orgs.Where(o => o.Key > 10), p => p.Value.OrganizationId, o => o.Key,
                    (p, o) => new { p, o })
                .GroupBy(x => x.o.Value.Name)
                .Select(g => new { Org = g.Key, AgeSum = g.Max(x => x.p.Value.Age) }).ToCacheQueryable().GetFieldsQuery().Sql;`

Comment: @tech2avinash this seems to work for me, the SQL looks correct and the query returns results.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn Can you try the sample console i created in .Net Core, here i'm able to reproduce the issue.[link](https://github.com/tech2avinash/ApacheIgniteLinqIssue)

Comment: @tech2avinash thank you very much, I can reproduce the issue now. Ticket filed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13754, will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

After grouping you can select only `Key` property or aggregation functions. Also LEFT JOIN should be written in different way.

```cs
var query = 
   from service in serviceCache
   join meetingService in meetingServiceCache on service.Value.ServiceId equals meetingService.Value.ServiceId into j
   from meetingService in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
   join meeting in meetingCache on meetingService.Value.MeetingId equals meeting.Value.MeetingId into j
   from meeting in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
   group new { service, meeting } by service.Value.ServiceId into g
   select new 
   {
       ServiceId = g.Key,
       lastMeeting = g.Max(x => x.meeting.Value.CreatedDate)
   };
```

Comment: I just verified, it’s still not working.Apache ignite linq translation is bit different from traditional linq to sql. With above changes the generated sql simply omitted the meetingService and meeting caches from sql.

Comment: Maybe it's time to uncover library that you have used? Add you `.ToCacheQueryable().GetFieldsQuery.Sql;` by yourself if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Ignite, I've filed a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13754).

The workaround is to reorder the joined tables and put `meeting` first, something like this:

```
var query = (from meeting in meetingCache
            join meetingService in meetingServiceCache.DefaultIfEmpty() on meeting.Value.MeetingId equals meetingService.Value.MeetingId
            join service in serviceCache service.Value.ServiceId equals meetingService.Value.ServiceId
            group new { service, meeting } by service.Value.ServiceId into g
            select new {
               service.Value.ServiceId,
               lastMeeting = g.Select(x=>x.meeting.Value.CreatedDate).Max()
            }).ToCacheQueryable().GetFieldsQuery.Sql;
```

Another workaround is to use raw SQL for this query.

Comment: Still getting the same issue after updating to 2.10.0

Comment: @tech2avinash Interesting, can you provide more details? The original [reproducer](https://github.com/tech2avinash/ApacheIgniteLinqIssue) works properly on 2.10 (there is an error regarding distributed joins, but the SQL is generated correctly)